# Как останавливаться перед препятствием

Tags: c#, wpf

Образно говоря, есть изображение танка, который может двигаться в любые стороны с помощью кнопок-стрелок на клавиатуре + картинка танка не вылезает за края (у края останавливается) + при этом сама картинка поворачивается, но у меня есть вручную нарисованные препятствия (**не рисунок**) и надо чтобы когда коснется препятствия остановиться

ниже код как он едет и останавливается перед окном + поворачивает (не идеально но в моем варианте работает как надо)

```
 if (e.Key == Key.Up)
            {
                TransformGroup tg;
                System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform rt;
                tg = image.RenderTransform as System.Windows.Media.TransformGroup;
                if (tg == null)
                {
                    tg = new System.Windows.Media.TransformGroup();
                    image.RenderTransform = tg;
                }
                rt = tg.Children.FirstOrDefault(x => x is System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform) as System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform;
                if (rt == null)
                {
                    rt = new System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform();
                    tg.Children.Add(rt);
                }
                rt.Angle = 90;
            }

            if (e.Key == Key.Right)
            {
                TransformGroup tg;
                System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform rt;
                tg = image.RenderTransform as System.Windows.Media.TransformGroup;
                if (tg == null)
                {
                    tg = new System.Windows.Media.TransformGroup();
                    image.RenderTransform = tg;
                }
                rt = tg.Children.FirstOrDefault(x => x is System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform) as System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform;
                if (rt == null)
                {
                    rt = new System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform();
                    tg.Children.Add(rt);
                }
                rt.Angle = 180;
            }

            if (e.Key == Key.Down)
            {
                TransformGroup tg;
                System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform rt;
                tg = image.RenderTransform as System.Windows.Media.TransformGroup;
                if (tg == null)
                {
                    tg = new System.Windows.Media.TransformGroup();
                    image.RenderTransform = tg;
                }
                rt = tg.Children.FirstOrDefault(x => x is System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform) as System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform;
                if (rt == null)
                {
                    rt = new System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform();
                    tg.Children.Add(rt);
                }
                rt.Angle = -90;
            }

            if (e.Key == Key.Left)
            {
                TransformGroup tg;
                System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform rt;
                tg = image.RenderTransform as System.Windows.Media.TransformGroup;
                if (tg == null)
                {
                    tg = new System.Windows.Media.TransformGroup();
                    image.RenderTransform = tg;
                }
                rt = tg.Children.FirstOrDefault(x => x is System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform) as System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform;
                if (rt == null)
                {
                    rt = new System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform();
                    tg.Children.Add(rt);
                }
                rt.Angle = 360;
            }





            if (e.Key == Key.Left)
                if (image.Margin.Left > 10)
                    image.Margin = new Thickness(image.Margin.Left - 15, image.Margin.Top, 0, 0);
                else
                    image.Margin = new Thickness(image.Margin.Left, image.Margin.Top, 0, 0);

            if (e.Key == Key.Right)
                if (image.Margin.Left < 1230)
                    image.Margin = new Thickness(image.Margin.Left + 15, image.Margin.Top, 0, 0);
                else image.Margin = new Thickness(image.Margin.Left, image.Margin.Top, 0, 0);

            if (e.Key == Key.Up)



                if (image.Margin.Top > 50)
                    image.Margin = new Thickness(image.Margin.Left, image.Margin.Top - 15, 0, 0);
                else
                    image.Margin = new Thickness(image.Margin.Left, image.Margin.Top, 0, 0);

            if (e.Key == Key.Down)
                if (image.Margin.Top < 660)
                    image.Margin = new Thickness(image.Margin.Left, image.Margin.Top + 15, 0, 0);
                else
                    image.Margin = new Thickness(image.Margin.Left, image.Margin.Top, 0, 0);
```

Пожалуйста сделайте пример кода!!!

Comment: Вам стоит отделить контент от представления. Создайте внутреннее представление поля и объектов, при каждом шаге проверяйте его возможность. Короче, нужно писать ещё довольно много.

Comment: ну а  пример хотяб

Comment: " у меня есть вручную нарисованные препятствия (не рисунок) " - на мониторе фломастером чтоле?

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот Вам пример.

```
public void Move(ref int x, ref int y, int a, bool[][]map)
{
  int nX = x + (a == 1 ? -1 : a == 3 ? 1 : 0);
  int nY = y + (a == 2 ? 1 : a == 4 ? -1 : 0);
  if(nX>=0 && nX<map.length)
    if(nY>=0 && nY<map[nX].length)
      if (!map[nX][nY])
      {
        x = nX;
        y = nY;
      }
}
```

PS:

`a`: 1-Лево; 2-Вверх; 3-право; 4-Вниз;

`map`: карта препятствий;